# Getting undefined with static get

Tags: javascript, class, static

I am learning classes in JS, and I have tried to see how `static get` works. From reading about it, I thought this would work:

```
class Builder {
  constructor() {
    this.number = 1;
  }

  static get increaseNumber() {
    return 1 + this.number;
  }
}

const builderInstance = new Builder();
```

But, I get `undefined` when I try to run this:

```
console.log(builderInstance.increaseNumber);
```

If I remove the `static` keyword then it works, why do I get `undefined` if I use `static`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get undefined because `increaseNumber` is static and you try to call it from an instance of `Builder`.

`static` is a `keyword` stating that the method will be callable by the class.

You cannot call a static method directly from the object.

[here](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/02/02/static-members-in-es6.aspx) is a tutorial explaining it

```js
class Builder {
  constructor() {
    this.number = 1;
  }

  static get increaseNumber() {
    return 1 + this.number;
  }
}

const builderInstance = new Builder();

console.log(builderInstance.increaseNumber);
```

---

Here is the appropriate implementation to call from an object :

An object represent an **instance** of a **class**

```js
class Builder {
  constructor() {
    this.number = 1;
  }

  get increaseNumber() {
    return 1 + this.number;
  }
}

const builderInstance = new Builder();

console.log(builderInstance.increaseNumber);
```

---

As you asked me from the comment, the following snippet returns `NaN`, why ?

```js
class Builder {
  constructor() {
    this.number = 1;
  }

  static get increaseNumber() {
    return 1 + this.number;
  }
}

console.log(Builder.increaseNumber);
```

Because you try to access to a property called `number` ; which is `undefined` and `1 + undefined` equals `NaN`.

When calling the static method, you are not executing the `constructor` and so the number is not initialized.

What you can do :

```js
class Builder {
  static get increaseNumber() {
    // We use || here to say "if it's not initialized, initialize it to 0"
    this.number = (this.number || 0) + 1;
    
    return this.number;
  }
}

console.log(Builder.increaseNumber);
console.log(Builder.increaseNumber);
console.log(Builder.increaseNumber);
console.log(Builder.increaseNumber);
```

Comment: But, then why do I get NaN when I try to call static method with class ```Builder.increaseNumber```?

Answer (score 2):

Like other languages with static class members, the *static* keyword will **create a method associated with the class**, and **not with an instance of the class**. In other words,

> you can only reach a static method using the name of the class

Comment: This probably should have been a comment rather than a new answer

Comment: you are right :)